# Why Chimera Ants who were created from humans have the physical appearance of animals?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

If I understand correctly, the Ant Queen can pass the genes of what she eats to her offsprings. And also, IIRC, she ate humans and created chimera ants like Colt, Peggy and Meleoron. These ants resemble a Condor, a Chameleon and a penguin, but they werent created eating animals but humans. How is this possible? Why Chimera Ants who were created from humans have the physical appearance of animals?

Answer (score 1):

I found a question on Reddit referring to exactly [that.](https://www.reddit.com/r/HunterXHunter/comments/37qqcz/how_do_the_later_generation_of_chimera_ants_have/)
Based on fan theories, they believe that since NGL is one giant nature preserve, the ant queen had access to all types of animals early on. The ant chimeras she makes then randomly inherit the animal genes she ingested.

Gearfire describes the process pretty well:

> That most likely has to do with the differences between Genotype and Phenotype. Just because the Chimera Ants were composed of mostly human DNA and genes doesn't mean that those genes are the ones that are physically expressed. The varied appearance of the ants seems to me like proof that human genes were not dominant in terms of outward appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Its either because...

1. Since the chimera ant is giving birth to them they are coming out as animals but

having human knowledge and mindset.
or because..

2. Or the chimera ant queen is eating more animals then humans for a certain chimera ant, but those chimera ant are still having human knowledge